# replicate table-cell property

Tags: html, css

I need a span inside of a td tag i am generating in a table.

in order to make to span fill the td I have defined it as an inline-block with width and height of 100%.  However if you start hitting the del key in the last cell it will start deleting content outside of the table.

if i define the span as a display: table-cell that prevents this but I have issues making it fill the parent td.  I need the span as it stops other content in the td being deleted.

Is there a CSS property that you can add to a class that makes it act more like a table-cell in terms of the delete only taking effect inside that container?

```
    <div contenteditable ="true">

<table contenteidtable ="false" class="a">
  <tbody contenteditable="false">
    <tr contenteditable="false">
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">1</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">2</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">3</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable="false">
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">4</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">5</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable="false">
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">7</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">8</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">9</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
Some text here
</p>
<br />
<br />
<table contenteidtable ="false" class="b">
  <tbody contenteditable="false">
    <tr contenteditable="false">
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">1</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">2</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">3</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable="false">
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">4</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">5</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">6</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr contenteditable="false">
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">7</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">8</span>
      </td>
      <td  contenteditable="false">
        <span contenteditable = "true">9</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
Some text here
</p>
</div>



    table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}

table,
/*table.gsm-i-tbl > tbody > tr > th,*/
tabl > tbody > tr > td{
    border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    border-spacing: 2px !important; 
}

/*table.gsm-i-tbl > tbody > tr > th,*/ 
table > tbody > tr > td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

table tr td {
  border: 1px dashed lightgrey;
  background-color: transparent;
}

table {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

table.a > tbody > tr > td > span {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: table-cell;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    background-color: coral !important;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

table.b > tbody > tr > td > span {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;   
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    background-color: coral !important;
    border: none !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wuo24jns/29/

The above jsfiddle has 2 tables in it.  The only difference between the tables is the first table has a span with a display type of table-cell, and the second as inline-block.

If you click cell 9 if the first table and press delete a few times it will only delete the content of the cell (which is correct) but this span doesn't fill the TD in this one.

The second table, the span fills each TD however, if you click cell 9 in the second table and start pressing the delete key it will suck in the content "some text here" which is outside of the table and start deleting that.

Comment: Can't reproduce, if i understand correctly.

Comment: made an edit so hopefully it will make more sense now

Comment: I see it now -- it doesn't happen in firefox (54.0.1) but it does in chrome. I've never seen `contenteditable`, anyone else familiar with it?

Comment: Looks like it only start in firefox v.55 (http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable). See the resources tab at the bottom (if you haven't seen it already).

Comment: Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fully covers it, but it might be a start. In the fiddle, I moved the styles for table b into the html and added 'scoped'.

```
<style scoped>
    table.b > tbody > tr > td > span {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;   
        display: inline-block;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        padding: 0px !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
        background-color: coral !important;
        border: none !important;
        outline: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

See this article: http://blog.frankmtaylor.com/2013/03/18/contenteditable-css-scoped-and-advanced-in-browser-editing/

That's another new one for me. Hope that helps.

Comment: ...It worked in FF, don't think it's working in chrome - although i'm not sure i have it turned on...

Comment: Thanks, sorry there were issues in chrome it seemed, i had to change what i was doing and went down a different path to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. You have the entire thing wrapped in `<div contenteditable ="true">`. All descendents inherit from that. Move the last `<p>` outside that div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

"If this attribute is not set, its default value is inherited from its parent element."